# query value in range of two fields

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table
`

```
table VALUES

from UNSIGNED INT 

to UNSIGNED INT

value VARCHAR(2) `
```

example of filling

```
0,100000,good
100001,200000,better
200001,300000,best
---
```

etc.

I need to query a `value` by number, e.g. *100* (is between 0 and 100000), should return *good*
199000 should return better, 200002 should return best

What SQL syntax should/can I use?

I'm trying rn to fill the table with exact values from the range, but the process takes too long, there are more then 200k of big ranges.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, I had to use `HAVING` statement

```
select * from VALUES having 100 >= `from` and 100 <= `to`;
```

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like a simple WHERE clause should be sufficient.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE lookup_range(ni INT)
BEGIN
    SELECT value FROM VALUES
    WHERE ni >= from and ni <= to;
END;
```

You can then call it using:

```
CALL lookup_value(100);
CALL lookup_value(199000);
```

Comment: yes, that's corect, I don't know who set a minus here